# `bool` on a generator expression in python

Tags: python, boolean, generator

Looking to understand the meaning of `bool` on a generator expression in python.

`bool(x for x in [])` yields `True`

`bool(x for x in [1, 2, 3])` yields `True`

`bool(range(0))` yields `False` (??)

`bool(range(3))` yields `True`

Comment: Generators are always truthy, like most non-container, non-numeric builtins

Comment: Note`range` **does not return a generator**. It returns a `range` object which isn't even an iterator, rather, it is an iterable sequence type

Comment: No surprises here. What's the question exactly?

Comment: when you give the range as 0 nothing comes out of it.. So it will return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The confusion arises from `range` not returning a generator.

In general generators are just objects and therefore are always truthy (as opposed to containers which are `False` when empty).

If you do `type(range(0))` you get "range", but it's not a generator, and apparently has an implicit truth value when it is empty vs non empty.

Answer (score 0):

bool returns true for 'truthy' values and false for 'falsy' values.

Case 1:

`(x for x in [])`

Creates a generator object.

Ouput:

`<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03DCDEF0>`

Since an object is generated, its Truthy and it returns True.

Case 2:

`(x for x in [1, 2, 3])`

Same as above

Case 3:

`(range(0))`

This is just range(0, 0).

Try this:

`for i in range(0): print(i)`

There will be no output.

You will not get any value, which is Falsy and False is returned.

Case 4:

`(range(3))`

Try this:

`for i in range(3): print(i)`

Ouput:

```
0
1
2
```

Values are returned which means its truthy and True is returned.

More on [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)